# Multiple errors :Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color2'

Tags: tables

In overleaf I have a lot of logs with the same statement :"Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `color2'." . I'm not using colors and I dont know where this error comes or how to fix it.

Antoher thing is that I'm trying to add an arrow to a table, but just for a new one arrow it trows me the same error.

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Tabla guía}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{Experimento 1} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{Experimento 2} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{Experimento 3} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{Experimento 4} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{Experimento 5} & \multicolumn{ 2}{l|}{} \\ \hline
Color & Con lente & Sin lente & Con lente & Sin lente & Con lente & Sin lente & Con lente & Sin lente & Con lente & Sin lente & Promedio lente & Promedio sin lente \\ \hline
Blanco &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Rojo &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Verde &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Azul &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
uv &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{Tabla guía 1}
\end{table}
```

If I delet the last arrow "uv" it works fine

Comment: If I complete your example, I don't get an error, regardless of whether or not I delete the last row "uv".

Comment: Did you copy some code from another example somewhere? If there is a reference to *color2* it probably is located somewhere in that code. Do a search for *color2* in your document.

Comment: *If I delete the last arrow "uv" it works fine* ... Did you mean *the last row "uv"* or is that *uv* somewhere defined as an arrow?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134144) that allows others to reproduce the error you get.